# Restrict to two keyboard inputs per second

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I am trying to make a simple game in HTML5 Canvas. I want, at most, two keyboard input per second.

This is my code so far:

```
function move( x, y, r ) {
  var canid=document.getElementById("draw");
  canid.addEventListener('keydown',readkey,false);

  function readkey(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
      clearField();
      x = x-draw.width / 10;
      redrawpic(x,y,r);
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 38){
      clearField();
      y = y-draw.height / 10;
      redrawpic( x, y, r );
    }

    //..........etc
  }
}
```

The function move is used to move picture from one cell to another. How to set delay a between two moves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a timestamp to check when the last event has occured:

```
function move(x,y,r){

   /* your variable declarations*/
   var d1 = Date.now();
   var d2;

        function readkey(e){
             d2 = Date.now();

             // difference between timestamps needs to be 500ms
             if(d2-d1 > 500){
                  // set old Timestamp to new one
                  d1 = d2;
                  /*
                     Rest of your code
                  */
             }
```

This allows one key event every 500ms. Not exactly the same like 2 events in 1 second (which could occure in 50ms and then pause 950ms), but maybe close enough?

Timeout/Interval is possible too, but I personally dislike the overhead of consecutive (possibly unnecessary) timeout calls.

Answer (score 3):

```
var throttle = false;
function readkey(e) {
    if (throttle)
        return;
    throttle = true;
    setTimeout(function () { throttle = false; }, 500);
    /* the rest of your code */
```

500ms is two inputs per second, but they are throttled individually.  You could also keep a count of how many inputs there have been in a full second.  Something like

```
    if (throttle > 1)
        return;
    throttle++;
    setTimeout(function () { throttle = 0; }, 1000);
```

Comment: +1 nice and clean solution (I prefer avoiding timeouts, but my call to Date.now() could even be costlier, I'm unsure about that).

Comment: Which one is the better method? setTimeout() or Date.now()?

Comment: @mridul I don't think one is better than the other